# ViewerJS str.replace how to make it work

Tags: javascript, html

I was taking a look at ViewerJS and seems like a good fit the only problem i found was title came out with %20 instead of space. I know why, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

so it looks like this code gets worked first. how would i fix it in here to make it display with no %20.

```
function getPDFFileNameFromURL(url) {
var reURI = /^(?:([^:]+:)?\/\/[^\/]+)?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$/;
//            SCHEME      HOST         1.PATH  2.QUERY   3.REF
// Pattern to get last matching NAME.pdf
var reFilename = /[^\/?#=]+\.pdf\b(?!.*\.pdf\b)/i;
var splitURI = reURI.exec(url);
var suggestedFilename = reFilename.exec(splitURI[1]) ||
                       reFilename.exec(splitURI[2]) ||
                       reFilename.exec(splitURI[3]);
if (suggestedFilename) {
suggestedFilename = suggestedFilename[0];
if (suggestedFilename.indexOf('%') !== -1) {
  // URL-encoded %2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.pdf should be file.pdf
  try {
    suggestedFilename =
      reFilename.exec(decodeURIComponent(suggestedFilename))[0];
  } catch(e) { // Possible (extremely rare) errors:
    // URIError "Malformed URI", e.g. for "%AA.pdf"
    // TypeError "null has no properties", e.g. for "%2F.pdf"
  }
}
}
return suggestedFilename || 'document.pdf';
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Try decodeURIComponent(), https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: @rackemup420 Did you try to post an issue on their Github repo https://github.com/kogmbh/ViewerJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = 'Some%20string%20with%20spaces';
x = x.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: does not work it breaks the pdf viewer part and the title does not get formatted